# Salesforce Lead.OwnerId not updating via .Net API wrapper

Tags: leads, update, .net, record-owner

We have a problem where the OwnerId field on the Lead object is not updating when we try and update it using [this Saleforce .Net API wrapper](https://github.com/wadewegner/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET).

The following process occurs.

1. New lead is created
2. Lead owner is set to a Queue via the "Default Lead Owner" functionality in "Lead settings"
3. The OwnerId field is a polymorphic Lookup of Lookup(User,Group)
4. Our code calls ForceClient.UpdateAsync passing in the LeadObject with OwerId set to a correct UserId
5. ForceClient.UpdateAsync returns a success boolean and no error message
6. The lead owner is not changed in Salesforce.

The code is rather simplistic:

```
public Response UpdateRecordsInSalesForce(string tableName, string recordId, object record, ForceClient client)
{
    var response = new Response();
    try
    {
        var recordSaved = client.UpdateAsync(tableName, recordId, record).Result;
        response.Success = recordSaved.Success;
        if (!recordSaved.Success)
        {
            response.Message = $"Failed to save record because {recordSaved.Errors}";
            _Log.Error(response.Message);
        }
```

We are new to integrating with the Saleforce API and I have seen a lot of answers mentioning triggers, etc. I have scoured our Saleforce instance and there does not seem to be anything undoing the update.

1. Has anyone run into a similar problem with Lead.OwnerId?
2. Can anyone think of a permission/ setting that we should check?

Comment: If you try to update any other fields together with OwnerId, does it work?

Comment: @kurunve we just tested changing Firstname & OwnerId. First name changed, but OwnerId did not change.